# How to understand the base64 encoding in vtk binary file format

Tags: binary, base64, vtk

I have a problem with how to understand the binary `DataArray`. The problem because of the base64 encoding.

The manual said if the format of `DataArray` is `binary`,

```
The data are encoded in base64 and listed contiguously inside the
DataArray element. Data may also be compressed before encoding in base64. The byte-
order of the data matches that specified by the byte_order attribute of the VTKFile element.
```

I can not fully understand that, so I have obtain ascii file and binary file for same model.

## ASCII file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="4" NumberOfCells="1">
      <PointData>
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii" RangeMin="0" RangeMax="1.4142135624">
          0 0 0 1 0 0
          1 1 0 0 1 1
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="ascii" RangeMin="0" RangeMax="3">
          0 1 2 3
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="ascii" RangeMin="4" RangeMax="4">
          4
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" format="ascii" RangeMin="10" RangeMax="10">
          10
        </DataArray>
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

## Binary file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="4" NumberOfCells="1">
      <PointData>
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="binary" RangeMin="0" RangeMax="1.4142135624">
          AQAAAACAAAAwAAAAEQAAAA==eJxjYEAGDfaobEw+ADwjA7w=
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="binary" RangeMin="0" RangeMax="3">
          AQAAAACAAAAgAAAAEwAAAA==eJxjYIAARijNBKWZoTQAAHAABw==
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="binary" RangeMin="4" RangeMax="4">
          AQAAAACAAAAIAAAACwAAAA==eJxjYYAAAAAoAAU=
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" format="binary" RangeMin="10" RangeMax="10">
          AQAAAACAAAABAAAACQAAAA==eJzjAgAACwAL
        </DataArray>
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

When I looked at the the DataArray, using the last one as an example, I can not create the relationship between `AQAAAACAAAABAAAACQAAAA==eJzjAgAACwAL` and `10`.

My understanding can be expressed using follow code, but it obtain `CggAAA==`.

```
#include "base64.h" // https://github.com/superwills/NibbleAndAHalf/blob/master/NibbleAndAHalf/base64.h
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int len;

    // first arg: binary buffer
    // second arg: length of binary buffer
    // third arg: length of ascii buffer
    char *ascii = base64((char *)&x, sizeof(int), &len);
    
    std::cout << ascii << std::endl;
    std::cout << len << std::endl;
    free(ascii);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone give me an explanation of how to convert?
Another relate topic can be see in

- https://discourse.vtk.org/t/error-when-writing-binary-vtk-files/4487/7

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found in disscusstion.

```
https://discourse.vtk.org/t/how-to-understand-binary-dataarray-in-xml-vtk-output/4489
```

The long extra data comes from the compressor header.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution and written the answer in [a VTK support question](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/binary-dataarray-in-xml-using-python-numpy-what-are-the-leading-int32-values/8013/2?u=bva99), but I am writing it here in case anyone comes here looking for the same issue as us two.

Note that I program in Python, but I believe there are `base64` and `zlib` functions in C++. Also, I use `numpy` to define arrays, but I believe `std::vector` can be equivalently used in C++.

So, suppose we want to write the single precision float32 array called "Points" in your example. If we suppose that a header type of "UInt32" is used, then in Python, we would do:

```py
import numpy as np
import zlib
import base64

# write the float array.
arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='float32')
# generate a zlib compressed array. This outputs a python byte type
arr_comp = zlib.compress(arr)

# generate the uncompressed header
header = np.array([ 1,  # apparently this is always the case, I think
                2**15,  # from what I have read, this is true in general
           arr.nbytes,  # the size of the array `arr` in bytes
       len(arr_comp)],  # the size of the compressed array
                  dtype='uint32')  # because of header_type="UInt32"

# use base64 encoding when writing to file
# `.decode("utf-8")` transforms the python byte type to a string
print((base64.b64encode(header_arr) + base64.b64encode(arr_comp)).decode("utf-8"))
```

The output is as expected:

```
AQAAAACAAAAwAAAAEQAAAA==eJxjYEAGDfaobEw+ADwjA7w=
```

The 2**15 is the argument that controls the size of the history buffer (or the “window size”) used when compressing data, according to the [zlib python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html). Not sure what that means though...

---

Edit: The above code only works if the size in bytes of the array is less than or equal to `2**15`. In the VTK support question I have expanded for the case where the array is larger. You have to divide it into chunks.